# Case Sensitivity of Action Names in Struts 2

Tags: struts2

Is there an easy way to make Struts 2 action names case insensitive? Currently I have the following action defined:

```
<action name="printTest" class="MyClass" >
  <result name="error">/WEB-INF/jsp/error.jsp</result>
  <result name="input">/WEB-INF/jsp/test.jsp</result>
  <result name="success">/WEB-INF/jsp/test.jsp</result>
</action>
```

If the user types URL `/app/printtest.do` instead of  `/app/printtest.do` this action is not executed.

Other then mod_rewrite on the httpd level or something like that, the only option that I know about right now is simply adding the same exact action and changing the name to `printtest`. Ideally it would be a simple config change to `struts.xml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No configurable option, AFAIK, for case insensitive mapping.

So, I believe  you have answered the question yourself: either Apache's mod_rewrite, or write the extra mappings in the config.

You could also write your own ActionMapper, extending [DefaultActionMapper](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/mapper/DefaultActionMapper.java.html) (method
`parseNameAndNamespace()` ),  but I suspect it would be overkill... :-)